# getSupportFragmentManager() inside a fragment inside a fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a navigation drawer activity and fragments are used for different items of the navigation drawer as usual. There is a tab layout in first item of navigation drawer. Tab layout has been implemented using viewpager. There is a map inside this viewpager.

What I want to do is call

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

But mapFragment is always null.

I spent more than 2 hours applying many methods but I couldn't succeed.

The problem here according to my knowledge is this. getActivity() method return the navigation drawer activity. getSupportFragmentManager() return the fragment attached to navigation drawer. But the map is not in that fragment. Map is inside the fragment within the view pager.

Can anyone suggest a method to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this `getChildFragmentManager();` to get the `FragmentManager` inside a `Fragment`

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use the code as follows:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```